# No "RAP application with a view" template when create RAP project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rap

I just began with RAP few weeks ago. I want to create a RAP project with custom view but that template is not show when I try create project. You can see in image below:

[image]

As I know. It's must be there with RAP Hello and RAP Mail template. Could anyone tell me why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, In Eclipse LUNA have no template to create `RAP Workbench Application with a View`.

But you can create a `RCP Workbench Application Template with a View`, and change Required Bundlers to RAP Bundlers

org.eclipse.ui ==> org.eclipse.rap.ui
...

Or you must create RAP Application from scratch.

I found tutorial [HERE](http://o7planning.org/web/fe/default/en/document/16616/eclipse-rap-for-beginners-workbench-application), hope help you:

Comment: I was struggling with it... Why they havent added templates ?